# The Windows SDK version 7.0 was not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have a console C++ project which uses Boost and Catch using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. It was building fine last night and today it says,

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(34,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 7.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".
```

Specifically, what doe this means?

```
The Windows SDK version 7.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK
```

I repaired Visual Studio and that didn't work so it's not Visual Studio. I can compile other C++ projects.

Web-searches doesn't really find Windows SDK version 7.0, there is Windows SDK for Windows 7.

I'm completely baffled by this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Very silly problem.

The second line, "Windows SDK Version" had somehow gotten 7 on it.

[image]